# How to print contents of a container using std::format

Tags: c++, format, c++20

Using [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), we can print a container as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
  fmt::print("{}\n", v);
}
```

Can I do the same in the c++20 standard library version?

Comment: c++20 format didn't support the range print utility, so you still need to use fmtlib to print vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formatting ranges is not a part of C++20 `std::format` but will be supported in C++23 (see [P2286](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2286r1.html)).